# Oracle, one user (application connection) multi concurrent session (multi thread connection)

Tags: oracle, hibernate, enterprise-architect

In a normal enterprise application, there just one user (set in hibernate.xml or other config) and multi concurrent connection/multi concurrent session (cos its multi threaded application).

so, will those ONE user's multi session interfare each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends what you mean by "interfere".

Your middle tier connection pool will open a number of physical connections to the database.  Sessions in the middle tier will request a connection from the pool, do some work, and return the connection to the pool.  Assuming that your connection pool is large enough to handle the number of simultaneous calls being made from your application (based on the number of sessions, the length of time each session needs a logical connection, and the fraction of "think time" to "action time" in each session), you won't experience contention due to opening connections.

Oracle is perfectly happy to run queries in multiple sessions simultaneously.  Obviously, though, there is the potential for one session to contend with another session for resources.  Two sessions might contend for the same row-level lock if they are both trying to update the same row.  If you have enough sessions, you might end up in a situation where CPU or RAM or I/O is being overtaxed and the load that one session creates causes performance issues in another session.  Oracle doesn't care which Oracle user(s) are involved in this sort of contention-- you'd have the same potential for interference with 10 sessions all running as 1 user as you would if there were 10 sessions running as 10 different users assuming the sessions were doing the same things.

Comment: I mean, all concurrent sessions use ONE oracle account, will oracle handle this? or Oracle just use session id to make it diff, not the user account ?

Comment: @lovespring - You'd have the same potential for interference with 10 sessions all running as 1 user that you would if there were 10 sessions running as 10 different users.  Assuming that the middle tier connection pool is opening a sufficient number of sessions to handle the load and that you're not adding more contention by middle tier sessions waiting for new connections to be opened or existing connections to be returned to the connection pool.